# Related entities are present in SQL but not in returned object

Tags: entity-framework

I have a class ManualJournal with a collection of JournalLines which I hope to have Explicitly loaded.  I have other such collections working fine.  I have used SQL Profiler and can see 2 JournalLines successfully being returned from the SQL query.  However the ManualJournal's JournalLines collection returned from EntityFramework has 0 items in it.

Can you think of any settings or mistakes that might cause this?

Or is there a way to log or debug what EntityFramework does with the returned data when populating the object in memory?  All the logging and debugging options I can see relate to the SQL, but for me the SQL is correct and it is EF's internals I want to debug.

Comment: when the objects are returned, they are automatically attached to the context. if the context has the appropriate item with their FK, they are automatically added to it (relationship fixup). either your relationship is not configured correctly, ManualJournal is not in the same context as the objects in the collection, or your FK is incorrect. You should include some code to help us helping you in tracking the problem down.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro - thanks for your reply.  Unfortunately the code is a bit all over the place so it would be a bit of a mission to post a useful example.  The thing is the relationship must be configured correctly enough, as the JournalLines are returned in the SQL query.  So EF understands the relationship enough to create that query in the first place.  Also, the lines are part of the ManualJournal query so I don't see how it can be part of a different context.  However obviously something is wrong - so there is definitely no way to track the decisions made internally by EF along the way?